# Exibir objetos diferentes com grupos iguais

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tentei de varias formas, obtive resultados diferentes alguns bons, outros nem tanto. Gostaria de fazer algo como armazenar o grupo/objetos no MySQL e exibir na tela usando PHP

Eu tenho esta tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de exibir um resultado semelhante a este(feito no photoshop):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até agora eu tenho este código:

```html
<?php
   include("connect.php");
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Grupos";
    $con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);

    while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){
        
for($Objeto =1; $Objeto <= 3; $Objeto++){
 echo $dado["$Objeto"] . "<br>";
   }     

}
?>
```

Mas ele exibe desta forma:

grupo1 10

20

grupo2 30

54

grupo3 2039

4433

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Para obter o resultado que você espera puramente com SQL, você pode usar UNION. Porém essa opção não serve caso você aumente a quantidade de objetos. Ela responde a sua necessidade com 2 objetos:

```
SELECT grupo, objeto1 FROM objetos
UNION
SELECT grupo, objeto2 FROM objetos
```

Prova: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f19f2/2/0

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Uma opção com JOIN, permitindo infinitos grupos e objetos.

### 2) RECOMENDADA: Opção ordenando diretamente pela SQL

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcbcb/30

```
SELECT g.grupo, o.objeto
FROM objetos o
LEFT JOIN grupos g ON g.id = o.grupoid
WHERE g.id IN (SELECT id FROM grupos ORDER BY grupo)
```

### 3) Opção ordenando pelo PHP

- não recomendada, exposta aqui apenas como exemplo

**Estrutura do Banco de Dados** (exemplo): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcbcb/14/0

A QUERY SQL retorna agrupada por grupos, porém o código PHP ordena da forma que você pediu na pergunta.

**ATENÇÃO:** esse código funciona desde que você sempre insira a mesma quantidade de objetos por grupo.

```
include("connect.php");

$consulta = "SELECT g.grupo, objeto 
FROM objetos o
LEFT JOIN grupos g ON g.id = o.grupoid";
$con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);

$objetos = [];
$grupos = [];
$qtdObjetosGrupoKey = '';

foreach($con->fetch_array() as $linha) { 
    if(!in_array($linha['grupo'], $grupos)) {
        $grupos[] = $linha['grupo'];
    }

    if(!isset($qtdObjetos)) {
        $qtdObjetos = [$linha['grupo']] => 0;
        $qtdObjetosGrupoKey = $linha['grupo'];
    }

    if(!isset($objetos[$linha['grupo']])) {
        $objetos[$linha['grupo']] = [];

    }

    $objetos[$linha['grupo']][] = $linha['objeto'];

    if(isset($qtdObjetos[$linha['grupo']])) {
        $qtdObjetos[$linha['grupo']]++;
    }
}

$itensPorGrupo = $qtdObjetos[$qtdObjetosGrupoKey];
$itemPos = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < $itensPorGrupo; $i++) {
    foreach($grupos as $grupo) {
        $resultado[] = [
            'grupo' => $grupo,
            'objeto' => $objetos[$grupo][$itemPos]
        ];
        $itemPos++;
    }
}

print_r($resultado);
```

Comment: Desta maneira até funcionou, mas toda a vez que eu colocar mais um objeto na tabela, eu tenho que repetir o UNION?

Comment: Sim, porém se você vai expandir a quantidade de objetos é melhor ter uma tabela para grupos e outra para objetos e fazer JOINs. Passei o exemplo de UNION caso realmente fossem apenas 2 objetos, caso contrário, dependendo do volume de dados, o SELECT ficará impraticável.

Comment: Estou  criando um exemplo com JOINS e já atualizo aqui.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta com o exemplo com JOINS. Ele é bem mais complexo no PHP, porém você terá robustez e infinito crescimento, sem precisar adicionar novas colunas ao banco.

Comment: A QUERY SQL retorna agrupada por grupos, porém o código PHP ordena da forma que você pediu na pergunta.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada, obrigado

Comment: A query SQL e o fiddle estavam errados, corrigi.

Comment: Eu gostei da sua pergunta, pois achei curioso a forma de ordenação. Assim, cheguei a uma forma infinitamente mais simplificada, editei a resposta. Seria com essa SQL: `SELECT g.grupo, o.objeto
FROM objetos o
LEFT JOIN grupos g ON g.id = o.grupoid
WHERE g.id IN (SELECT id FROM grupos ORDER BY grupo)`

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM Grupos";
$con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);

foreach($con->fetch_array() as $linha) { 
    $grupo[] = $linha['Grupo'];
    $obj1[] = $linha['Objeto1'];
    $obj2[] = $linha['Objeto2'];
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($grupo);$i++) {
    echo $grupo[$i];
    echo $obj1[$i];
    echo $obj2[$i];
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```